# Ansible configure and make

Tags: makefile, ansible, configure

Configure and make not working as separate steps.

```yaml
- name: configure
  command: ./configure --with-python=/usr/local/bin/python2.7
  args:
    chdir: "/usr/src/mod_wsgi-{{ mod_wsgi_version }}"
- name: make
  command: make
  args:
    chdir: "/usr/src/mod_wsgi-{{ mod_wsgi_version }}"
```

However, when I combine them in a single command line they work fine.

```yaml
- name: configure and make
  command: ./configure --with-python=/usr/local/bin/python2.7; make
  args:
    chdir: "/usr/src/mod_wsgi-{{ mod_wsgi_version }}"
```

My understanding was that configure is building a makefile and not doing something magic in the environment. Am I wrong?

Edit:
I got a lead, python is failing to run properly, because it requires a environment variable: LD_LIBRARY_PATH.

**I found the root cause. When I install python I edit the /etc/profile but this is ignored by the ansible login. Hence the LD_LIBRARY_PATH was not getting set. I have since updated the python installer playbook to add a shell script to /etc/profile.d/**

Comment: Odd.  That first playbook looks like it should work.  Can you run it with -vvvv and provide the debugging output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the root cause. When I install python I edit the `/etc/profile` but this is ignored by the ansible login. Hence the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` was not getting set. I have since updated the python installer playbook to add a shell script to `/etc/profile.d/`

Surprisingly the configure step wasn't erroring out, even though it was failing to properly run python. Probably because the configure script wasn't returning non-zero.